Excel duplicate every 10 rows of data
I have a column with numbers 1 through 20. In the next column, I would like the numbers to go from 1 through 10, then 1 through 10 again, then do 11 through 20, and then 11 through 20 again.
How can I do this.
Example output of what I need:

This is similar to my other question: Excel duplicate ever 10 rows of data and then reverse order, but I no longer need the numbers in reverse order

Try using the following:


• Formula used in cell B1
=LET(α, WRAPCOLS(A1:A20,10), TOCOL(VSTACK(α,SORT(α)),2,1))


Or,
=LET(α, WRAPCOLS(SEQUENCE(20),10), TOCOL(VSTACK(α,SORT(α)),2,1))


Edit: This is bit shorter:
=LET(α, WRAPCOLS(A1:A20,10), TOCOL(VSTACK(α,α),,1))


